# "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument" when setting up MFMailComposeViewController (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]

I upgraded to Xcode 7, and got these warnings in my email sending function. The same warnings occur in my text message function (MFMessageComposeViewController). What should I do?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've got it to work! For the recipients, I changed the line of code to:

```
composer setToRecipients:nil];
```

And for the subject and message body, I put an empty string like this:

```
[composer setSubject:@""];
[composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since iOS9 these parameters marked as nonnull parameters, there fore you should not pass nil to them. If you want them blank pass an empty string and nil to the recipients.

```
[composer setSubject:@""];
[composer setMessageBody:@"" isHTML:NO];
[composer setToRecipients:nil]
```

Comment: maybe you should fill out the recipients field as well

[composer setToRecipients:@[@""]];

you can fiind more information how to is component properly in the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/

Comment: Ok, I think I got it to work. I simply changed the line of code to:         [composer setToRecipients:nil]; and the field is blank which is what I wanted. And since your solution worked for the subject and message body, I'm gonna accept your answer!